# Unable to view state data in redux dev tools

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-devtools

[image]I am learning redux and came up with an example using a webservice that 
returns data. Everything is working. However I configured the redux developer tools
below.

I got an error saying my store is assigned a value but never used and when I go into
my dev tools, I am not able to see my state data. Am i doing something wrong?

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
        import promise from 'redux-promise';
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
        import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

        import reducers from './reducers';
        import ProductsIndex from './components/products_index';

        const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

        const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
        const store = createStore(
          reducers,
          composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware())
        );

        ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
           <Router>
            <div>
              <Route path="/" component={ProductsIndex} />
            </div>
           </Router>
          </Provider>
          , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Error: Line 14:7:  'store' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

[image]

Comment: Could you please change `const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);` to `const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(store);` and put it right after `store` initialization. Not sure about the `applyMiddleware` syntax let's try and see.

Comment: Or you can do something like this:
`const middleware = [promise];`
`const composEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;`
`const enhancer = composEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware));`

`const configureStore = (initialState?: any) => {
  return createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer);
};`
`<Provider store={configureStore()} >`

Comment: None of this work for me

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: From the first solution you provided, I got TypeError: createStore.apply is not a function

Comment: And second one?

Comment: const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware())
);

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(store);

Comment: I just added a screen shot of the error I was getting from the second solution. The state is now displayed though in the dev tools

Comment: Oh my bad please remove that `?: any` it's a typescript

Comment: Thanks. Removed and works great. Out of curiosity, if I decide to use a redux thunk in the future, where will it go?

Comment: I'll post an answer with thunk included

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do.

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import createRootReducer from "../reducers";

const middleware = window.ENV.environment === "local" ? [thunk, logger] : [thunk];
const composEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const enhancer = composEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware));

const configureStore = (initialState) => {
  return createStore(createRootReducer(), initialState, enhancer);
};

export default configureStore;
```

**App.js**

```
import configureStore from "./configureStore";
const store = configureStore();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        // ...
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```